# How to sample data from Pandas Dataframe based on value count from another column

Tags: python, pandas, sample

I have a dataframe of about 400,000 observations.  I want to sample 50,000 observations based on the amount of each state that's in a 'state' column.  So if there is 5% of all observations from TX, then 2,500 of the samples should be from TX, and so on.

I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df.sample(n=50000, weights = 'state', random_state = 101)
```

That gave me this error.

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int`
```

Is there a different way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weights modify the probability of any one row to be selected, but can’t provide strict guarantees on counts of given values, as you want. For that you would need `.groupby('state')`:

```
>>> rate = df['state'].value_counts(normalize=True)
>>> rate
TX    0.5
NY    0.3
CA    0.2
>>> df.groupby('state').apply(lambda s: s.sample(int(10 * rate[s.name]))).droplevel('state')
   state  val
69    CA   33
19    CA   99
37    NY   89
36    NY   63
75    NY    3
42    TX   42
53    TX   52
50    TX   68
72    TX   70
2     TX   18
```

Replace `10` with the number of samples you want, so `50_000`. This gives slightly more flexibility than the more efficient answer by @Psidom.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`groupby.sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.sample.html):

```
df.groupby('state').sample(frac=0.125, random_state=101)
```

`weights` parameter is different from groups, it expects list of numbers as sample probability which is used when you want non equal probability weighting for different rows.

For instance the following `sample` will always return a data frame from the first two rows since the last two rows have weights of 0 and will never get selected:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4]})
df.sample(n=2, weights=[0.5,0.5,0,0])
   a
0  1
1  2
```